# Can $3x^2+2x+\sqrt{16-x^2}$ equal 0?

Tags: linear-algebra

Derived from
$$f(x)=\frac{3x+2}{\sqrt{16-x^2}} + \frac{1}{x}$$

I'm not sure if I derived $3x^2+2x+\sqrt{16-x^2}$ correctly from the function above so please correct me if it's wrong, thanks!

Comment: Please, choose the tags carefully. This question is not about linear algebra.

Comment: @jjagmath I'm sorry, I don't even know what other types of algebra there are. If someone could tell me what algebra this is I would be very thankful!

Answer (score 1):

I did not check your derivative.  For the question Hints:  Consider the quadratic separately from the semicircle.  since $\sqrt{16-x^2}\geq 0$,  it is only 0 if the quadratic part is 0 when the semicircle is 0 ($\pm 4)$,  or you need the the quadratic to be negative and have the same magnitude/absolute value as the semicircle part at that point

So look at the graph of $3x^2 +2x$ and check A:  What values of $x$ is it negative for and b:  What is the range, i.e how negative can it get in that region?

Then look at the semicircle and check the range for the same values of x.   If those ranges don't overlap in magnitude, they can never add to 0.

Answer (score 0):

$y= (3x+ 2)(16- x^2)^{-1/2}+ x^{-1}$
The derivative is
$y'= 3(16- x)^{-1/2}+ (3x+ 2)x(16- x^2)^{-3/2}- x^{-2}$